# Spring Filter chain - antMatchers(...).authenticated() not being enforced

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an application using a custom Jwt token implementation.
The authentication portion works just fine, with the token being created/validated just fine. My Security configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DJWTSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/*").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/signin").permitAll()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
}
```

For some reason, security is not being enforced to api requests. For requests sent without bearer header, it seems that Spring considers "anonymous" users as being authenticated. Inspecting the security context:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@f27f7551: 
Principal: anonymousUser; 
Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; 
Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; 
SessionId: null; 
Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

Is this expected behavior that should be fixed by adding a role constraint to the route?

Comment: There is a difference between `authenticated` and `fullyAuthenticated`. Also are you sure your antmatchers are correct? as `/api/*` will only match a single level, so `/api/auth/whatever` will not be detected(as that is 2 levels deep). Also your ordering is off, as the order in which matchers are declared is also the one in which they are consulted. So if you really want a `/api/**` (all levels) it should always be last.

Comment: Yep. Mindlessly copied stuff over from another project. You're right on all of the points. It was the wildcard. Ordering should be the other way around too...

Answer (score 1):

- Wildcard was wrong - it should be `/api/***`
- not relevant for the given error, but the order should be the other way around